# Google apps won't let go of my email after canceling account

Tags: g-suite

I have a domain, example.com. I thought I might give Google apps a try so I signed up with me@example.com. I set up a friend with friend@example.com in Google apps. I decided I just wanted to manage my own mail so I deleted friend@example.com, cancelled the service for example.com, and deleted the example.com apps account. Now I try to email to me@example.com and Google is giving me an error before it can get to my mail server at myhostingcompany.com. The rejection reply is as follows:

```
Technical details of permanent failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain example.com (I changed this in this post) by aspmx.l.google.com. [2a00:1450:4010:c03::1a].

The error that the other server returned was:
550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try
550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or
550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at
550 5.1.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 un3si22009331lbb.21 - gsmtp
```

Comment: Remember -- at some point, you modified your DNS records to use Google. Undo that step.

Answer (score 7):

You need to change your MX records to point to your new email host.